# Where to put bounty information?

Tags: discussion, bounty, formatting

Sparked by a [chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7982823#7982823) about [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251771/how-can-i-use-the-new-kernel-signed-packages-to-keep-uefi-enabled-and-use-ubun), I think we should think of a way to put some order to bounty information.

## What information is interesting?

Sometimes, one would like to include information as to *what is expected from an answer* for it to gain a bounty, or *state reasons* for the bounty, or *announce a bounty yet to come* (which just can't be placed at that point).

All of these are valuable information when "advertising" a bounty.

## Discuss

1. Should we allow such advertisements about bounties, and to what extent?
2. Where should this information be put, and how should it be indicated?

What I'd like to see here is a clear way in which we should deal with such meta-information within the Q&A, while it has nothing to do with the question itself - even if that way is just "leave it be".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Just put it in the bounty box

[image]

There!

> Should we allow such advertisements about bounties, and to what extent?
>   Where should this information be put, and how should it be indicated?

So, to me, this seems already present in the system and such information should not belong in the body of the question.

If you feel this field is too limited in terms of revising, formatting, etc., then this should be a feature request on [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). I do think this message could be improved in terms of visual attention. Its fixed formatting is currently easily overlooked.

Answer (score -1):

I am giving *two* separate answers to this, because I deem both viable, and I can't precisely say which of the two I'd prefer - much less if the community agrees with either.

## Put it in the comments

Essentially, information *about* the bounty is meta-information. It has nothing to do with the question itself, so it shouldn't be part of the question. The bounty remarks, on the other hand, can't be changed afterwards *at all*, vanishes automatically and can't be responded to directly, so they feel insufficient for that.

Essentially, I'd like to see a comment at the beginning, stating something like this:

> **This question will get a bounty of 250 reputation once a clear answer detailing X and why not Y, is needed.**

Then, if there were questions about the meta-information, these could become part of a subsequent conversation in the comments.

Comment: "The bounty remarks can't be changed afterwards at all" <-- for a reason! When I put a bounty on it, I "pay" for it. So I can decide what I type there. I lost my rep for it already at that point and people may already have begun writing answers for it. Changing it afterwards would not be fair.

Comment: @gertvdijk Assuming you receive an answer for a running bounty. The answer lacks something important you would *also* like to see. How would you inform *other* posters (the answer can be commented) that this is *another* important point?

Comment: My opinion. Depends on how much *off* this is compared to the initial requirements. If it has changed considerably, e.g. "No, I want to know it for KDE as well!" then it's simply invalid and you should be more careful to start with. Solution: start a new bounty and you've paid rep to learn from. If it's a minor detail that is generally improving the post, e.g. "Would you care to include how to make this change persistent across reboots?" then I guess this is fine to add as a comment to the given answer.

Comment: @gertvdijk Just quoting myself from the chat here "It *[The remark on its own]* has serious disadvantages in terms of communication. You can't discuss the bounty, you can't edit the remark to globally indicate a change, it remains in the history only, once done and it can't be detailed beforehand (especially nice if you don't want to waste a large bounty without a pre-existing answer)."

Comment: Comments are a very bad place to put such information.

Answer (score -2):

I am giving two separate answers to this, because I deem both viable, and I can't precisely say which of the two I'd prefer - much less if the community agrees with either.

## Put it into the question itself

A dedicated bloc of text, perhaps at the end of the question (example below), could be constantly edited, sufficiently separated and have proper formatting, as opposed to comments or the bounty remarks.

> ---
>
> ## This question will receive a bounty of 50 reputation!
>
> However, we need an answer that contains all of the following:
>
> 1. A step-by-step manual how to do this.
> 2. Sources for further reading.
> 3. Kittens.
> 4. Optionally, screenshots for the steps.
>
> The bounty will be awarded to an existing answer, to avoid it running
>   out beforehand.

Comment: This already is implemented.

Comment: @BrunoPereira This isn't a feature-request and I don't recall that we have *policy* about this.

Comment: No one said this is or not a feature request. Just stating the obvious here.